# Horizontal scroll in multi layer drop down meny (css)

Tags: css, scroll

I have a multi drop down menu with several layers in CSS, and a vertical scroll for the longer parts. The problem is that when I hover a part in a submenu that leads to another submenu, that new submenu is confined within the "box" created by the first submenu (and its overflow) and you have to scroll horizontally to see the new submenu, instead of it appearing next to the old submenu. How do I create a new "box" outside the first one instead of inside it, so that I never have to scroll horizontally when I have several submenus and subsubmenus?

This is a simplified version of the code (the part that controls the appearance of all the submenus):

```
#navbar li ul { 
  display: none;
  max-height:800px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width:auto;
  }
```

And this is the code that controls the display of more submenus when hovering an element:

```
#navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul { 
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 z-index: 20000;
 -o-transition: all 1.7s ease-out 1s;
 -webkit-transition: all 1.7s ease-out 1s;
 -moz-transition: all 1.7s ease-out 1s;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the a simplified version of your code?

Comment: Ok so I've added some code now, the parts that are relevant for this issue =)

Comment: The parent `li` i.e `#navbar li`, must be having `overflow: auto` set, remove that.

Comment: But then won't the vertical scroll disappear too? That one I want to keep.

Comment: A JSFiddle of your code might help.